# Read file and match with file name

Tags: regular-expression

I have a text file I am trying to read from. Lets say that foo.txt contains:

```
foo.org
foo.com
foo.net
foo
bar.org
bar.com
bar
blah.org
example.org
```

And I am need to read this file and grep for pattern matching on filenames (NOT content within the files)

All the filenames will be something like:

foo.org.db
foo.com.db
bar.org.db

(They will all have .db at the end as they are zone files).

I have been trying something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=foo.txt
DIR=/path/to/zone/files
MATCH=match.txt
NO_MATCH=nomatch.txt

read -r line; do
   for a in $DIR
   do  
       if [ line =~ $a ]
       then
          echo "$line" >> "$MATCH"
       else
          echo "$line" >> "$NO_MATCH"
   done
done< $FILE
```

When running this script, i see $MATCH created but never $NO_MATCH. And it doesn't seem like the conditionals are working. I really need anything that doesn't match to be written to a text file. So for example, if example.org is written in the $FILE variable, but there is no filename match (no example.org.db), then example.org should be written to $NO_MATCH. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is *"pattern matching on filenames"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the inner loop and there's a `while` missing:

```
while read -r name; do
    files=$( echo "$DIR/$name"* )
    if [[ "$files" != "$DIR/$name"* ]]; then
        echo "$name" >>"$MATCH"
    else
        echo "$name" >>"$NO_MATCH"
    fi
done <"$FILE"
```

`echo "$DIR/$name"*` will expand to all filenames matching the given pattern.  If there are no filenames matching that pattern, the pattern will remain unexpanded.

Comment: Sorry, i was typing the snippet out from my memory.

Comment: Thats not working either.. It seems that lines that are matching are still being added to NO_MATCH

Comment: @ryekayo Still? You said they were added to `$MATCH` in the question...  In any case, double-check the `$DIR` value to make sure it's correct.  You may also want to `rm -f "$MATCH" "$NO_MATCH"` in the beginning of the script, or at least be aware that the script will only ever _append_ to those two files.

Comment: Oh im aware of that. I removed the text files before running but no it is still not working correctly.

Comment: @ryekayo Run the script with `bash -x script.sh` to get tracing output. That way you may be able to easier debug what's wrong.

Comment: Looks like it is always appending to NO_MATCH

Comment: But to be clear, what i am looking for is the contents of the text file to be a partial match to the filenames in the directory (if so, thats when they append to $MATCH, if not append to $NO_MATCH)

Comment: @ryekayo _Partial_ match? In what way? You never mentioned this...

Comment: @ryekayo Ah. I see. I will update.

Comment: Yes I did.. Look at the 2nd paragraph of my quesiton